# Failure to run xampp

Tags: jquery, xampp

I can't seem to get jquery load php file function to work in xampp and localhost.
But this code works correctly on the server and website when uploading.

```
<button type="button" onclick="foo()">Click Me</button>
<p id="ss"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function foo () {

      $.ajax({
        url:"file.php", //the page containing php script
        type: "POST", //request type
        success:function(result){
            alert(result);
       }
     });
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Does file.php exist in the same directory as the file?

Comment: Yes, the file exists.